# AWS CloudWatch Dashboard: how to show EC2 instance name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using CloudWatch dashboard to monitor EC2 instances. Name tag for EC2 instance is shown besides the instance id in the charts when I login as **root** user

However when I login as a user with only list and read permissions for CloudWatch and EC2 then charts's legends are appeared without EC2 instance name tag. It's very frustrating to switch back and forth between EC2 management console and CloudWatch dashboard mapping instance id and EC name tag

I suspect that I need to add more permissions to the user, but cannot figure out what permissions are needed exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ec2:describeInstances
- ec2:describeTags
- ec2:describeVolumes

See: [Permissions Required to Use the CloudWatch Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/iam-identity-based-access-control-cw.html#console-permissions-cw)

Or just attach AWS Managed Policy: **CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess** – Grants read-only access to CloudWatch.

Comment: "**CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess**" only was not enough to see the EC2 instance names. But after adding these access rights to the IAM user that have access to the Cloudwatch dashboard the instance names appeared on the graphs.

- ec2:describeInstances
- ec2:describeTags
- ec2:describeVolumes